# CentOS access.conf setting not working well?

Tags: centos

I have a CentOS machines and below I set this in my `access.conf`:

```
root : ALL
```

Yet I can login via root and still perform tasks. So what is the job of `access.conf` then? Is there anything wrong done here?

Comment: it is a way to manage access control. If you have multiple IP on your network then you may define the access for root/or user from specific IP in this file. Give it a try block the access for user root for your IP and try to access the server. Make sure that you have already opened another session before making the changes and logging out from the server so that you can revert back the changes.

Comment: @PratapSingh I would like to clarify what does this means  - : root : ALL. It means that root cant access from any ip am I right? So why is it that the root can still access here is where I am lost.

Comment: If you read the access.conf itself you would see you need to add `+ OR -` before any access control declaration.

Comment: @PratapSingh yes I have read it say if - you dont give access to root and ALL is from any ip right? Please correct me here. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go and get to know how to activate access.conf

I did add following in my access.conf file

```
[root@lcoalhost ~]# tail -1 /etc/security/access.conf
-:user1:ALL
```

I added the following in the file "/etc/pam.d/sshd"

```
[root@localhost ~]# head -3 /etc/pam.d/sshd
#%PAM-1.0
auth       include      system-auth
account    required     pam_access.so   #I added this line in the file
```

Specially the 3rd line.

After editing this I tried accessing the server as user **`:user1:`**

This is what I saw in the log file **"/var/log/secure"**

```
Jan  1 16:40:06 localhost sshd[17981]: pam_access(sshd:account): access denied for user `user1' from `10.0.1.243'
Jan  1 16:40:06 localhost sshd[17981]: Failed password for user1 from 10.0.1.243 port 3186 ssh2
Jan  1 11:10:06 localhost sshd[17982]: fatal: Access denied for user user1 by PAM account configuration
```

Here "user1" has been denied from any IP. Similarly you can do it for any user.

Here is the log for `root` user

```
Jan  1 16:53:29 localhost sshd[19144]: pam_access(sshd:account): access denied for user `root' from `10.0.1.243'
Jan  1 16:53:29 localhost sshd[19144]: Failed password for root from 10.0.1.243 port 3356 ssh2
Jan  1 11:23:29 localhost sshd[19145]: fatal: Access denied for user root by PAM account configuration
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess I miss the second part the pam setting which I have not done yet. So the pam settings must be done in order for access.conf to work am I right? I also saw this line in my pam auth required pam_wheel.so use_uid what does this do then is the same functionality?

Comment: `Yes` the pam settings must be enabled in order to get it working. Because it just scan the file in order it is given in the file. To know more about this you might need to do some search [link](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_wheel).

Comment: I would like to know the steps here.So first when I ssh into a machine the access.conf file will be scan and followed by pam is it? OR is the other way around?

Comment: Yes this is the way it works as per the details.

Comment: I am lost which one is checked first the access.conf or pam.d? I guess is the pam right? So then pam will look for the access.conf?

Comment: PAM stands for Pluggable Authentication Module [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-pam-configuration-that-allows-or-deny-login-via-the-sshd-server.html) and pam.d is checked as soon as the ssh service is started and all the modules were loaded too. At the time when user try to attempt login then access.conf is checked.  So in your word "Yes first pam.d files are checked then it checks the access.conf file". Hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: thank you very much because all this while I was never clear about this PAM now I am much clearer on how the fundamentals work which makes you feel more confidence.